# Logo is not showing in Joomla driven website

Tags: php, css, joomla

Thanks for reading this and helping me out with this! I tried everything I could to find out what's going on here, the logo is showing only in the homepage. All the pages share the same template and the CMS is Joomla. I inspected the path of the image and it seems fine but why is it not showing in other pages? I'm a newbie with Joomla and this is the only place where I believe I can get an explanation regarding the issue. Could you please spend a minute and check the codes inspecting them? This is the site http://targetlabs2.net/mazani/

Comment: Check where the imgs source attribute points to and you have your answer... You probably want to do this using your browsers developer console or by looking at the pages source.

Comment: @arkascha thanks for your answer. As I have mentioned, I already inspected them and the path is the same in the homepage where the logo is actually showing, and other pages where it isn't.

Comment: Then what does the http servers error log file report when the browser requests the file? And what does the browser console report upon that reference?

Comment: @arkascha, thanks for trying to help me :) Mark Simpson's solution solved the problem.

Comment: Fine if the problem has gone away for you :-) However I have the impression you only cured a symptom, but are not really able to find the cause of such problem yourself... Forgive me if I am wrong, but you really should learn how to debug such things yourself, that is what I tried to guide you towards...

Comment: @arkascha, I really appreciate you're trying to help me here. Actually I inspected the image's path many times and the logo should have been displayed in all the pages as they share the same template. What actually happened there was the url wasn't SEO friendly leaving url structure one level up from the actual template the pages share. After turning the SEO friendly url and url re-writing options on the logo issue along with the broken url is gone. 
I hope this thread will help others facing the same issue. Thanks again for your helpful manner :)

Comment: If you really knew all this whilst writing the question, then why did you not write those details? ;-) Have fun!

Comment: Actually I got it after @Mark Simpson provided the solution. Following his solution I saw the url structure changed to the desired one and I realized that's what causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Joomla global configuration, make sure you have SEF (Search Engine Friendly) URL's turned on with mod_rewrite.

Then clear your Joomla cache.

That should remove the index.php in your URL's, fixing the broken logo on subpages.

Comment: thanks so much! I knew I could get a solution here :) Yeah it's fixed now.

Comment: Glad it worked :)

Please mark the answer correct when you have a spare moment.

Comment: I marked it already. I have another issue I'd like to share here, or should I create a new thread? I tried every solution out there including the php.ini and .htaccess modification but nothing seems to work in order to disable the magic quote option in Joomla. It's very painful. Is there any way to prevent Joomla custom module to output those extra quotes manually? There should be any trick to cheat php to escape the HTML entities being added each time I update and save the posts.

Comment: @user2951941 Thanks. Yeah definitely create a new question for that issue. Partly because SO prefers each question to address a single issue, but more so because I'm not a PHP guy so can't help you there. There are much smarter Joomla people than I on here and you'll get more eyes on the problem if you post it as a new question.